# Converting Keybase.io Login Algorithm to Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, encryption, hash, cryptography, hmac

### I am trying to build a Objective-C client for *KeyBase.io*. Some of the String specifics are getting the best of me however.

#### Consider this pseudocode from the [Keybase api docs](https://keybase.io/__/api-docs/1.0#call-login):

```
pwh = scrypt(passphrase, hex2bin(salt), N=215, r=8, p=1, dkLen=224)[192:224]
```

I believe that a half correct Objective-C mapping would be (scrypt function from Tarsnap and [helper category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339123/2127731)) :

```
uint8_t *passphrase = (uint8_t *)[@"AVeryCleverPassword1" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding].bytes;
uint8_t *salt = (uint8_t *)@"32355c2e7843513463263...".decodeFromHexidecimal.bytes;
uint8_t buffer[224];

crypto_scrypt(passphrase, 20, salt, 24, pow(2, 15), 8, 1, buffer, 224);
uint8_t *pwh = buffer + 192;
```

The buffer looks like this which doesn't make sense.

```
[0] = '\xa4'
[1] = '\xb4'
[2] = '\xca'
[3] = '\x17'
[4] = '\xcc'
[5] = '\xa6'
[6] = '\xc7'
[7] = 'n'
```

#### **Going further** consider this next step:

```
hmac_pwh = HMAC-SHA512(pwh, base64decode(login_session))//hmac_pwh is hex encoded
```

I believe a correct mapping looks like this with [a helper category](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64):

```
NSData *decodedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:@"lgHZIDhlY2I0..."];
uint8_t *decodedCString = (uint8_t *)decodedData.bytes;
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA512, pwh, 224 - 192, decodedCString, 108, cHMAC);
```

the cHMAC buffer doesn't look right either: "\xca\x93 \xc2\xd7"\xfe\xd7\xc9\xa8..."

When converting the cHMAC string back into a NSString, my suspicions are confirmed as

```
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *HMACString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:HMAC encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Results in HMACString looking like this "Ê Â×"þ×É¨©..."

I believe this is a encoding/decoding issue since NSString is UTF-8 encoded but I can officially say that it's above my head. Does cHMAC need to be decoded from binary into hexadecimal before being encoded as a string?

**Any help, however small, would be appreciated.**

### Answer:

The answer is that I wasn't encoding/decoding to and from hex to binary as pointed out by Max.

To get from cHMAC to a NSString representation of HMAC you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195028/2127731). My interpretation:

```
NSString* hmac(unsigned int size, unsigned char cHMAC[size])
{

  NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     [result appendFormat:@"%02hhx", cHMAC[i]];
  }

  return result;
}
```

And invoked as such:

```
NSString *result = hmac(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH, cHMAC);
```

Comment: Do decode hex into NSData (for the salt), you need to run a little function like the one shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338975/convert-hex-data-string-to-nsdata-in-objective-c-cocoa

Comment: That looks correct, question updated! Thank you! I still do not understand why HMACString comes back all garbled after encoding. Does it need to be converted to hexidecimal from binary?

Comment: Yes! You'd use the reverse of the code from that stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Thats it! You are correct! It worked!!!

Comment: @MaxKrohn You should post that as an answer so you can get the appropriate credit for it. :)